# Scaling texture in SFML

Tags: c++, user-interface, sfml

I am trying to make a grid of size 400 * 400 (pixels).

Then, I'm loading a texture, and intending to scale it to 20 * 20. So 400 of them will fit.

```
void gameLoop()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), "Minesweeper");

    // Create the grid of sprites with the texture
    std::vector<std::vector<sf::Sprite>> grid(DEFAULT_ROWS_NUM, std::vector<sf::Sprite>(DEFAULT_COLS_NUM));

    sf::Texture unrevealedEmptyTexture;
    if (!unrevealedEmptyTexture.loadFromFile("Images/unrevealed_empty.png"))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load texture." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Set the position and scale of each sprite
    for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_ROWS_NUM; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < DEFAULT_COLS_NUM; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j].setTexture(unrevealedEmptyTexture);
            grid[i][j].setPosition(i * CELL_SIZE, j * CELL_SIZE);
            grid[i][j].setScale(CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
        }
    }

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::White);

        drawBoard(window, grid);

        window.display();
    }
}
```

`DEFAULT_ROWS_NUM` is 20.
`DEFAULT_COL_NUM` is 20.

`WINDOW_WIDTH` is 400.
`WINDOW_HEIGHT` is 400.

`CELL_SIZE` is 20.

What goes wrong, is that the image does not scale. I know that because I only see the top left part of the image, which means it is huge in relation to the window... like outside of it.

My question is, how do I scale it so it will work like I want (20 in each row)?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `grid[i][j].setScale(CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);`? If you create a sprite from a texture then by default it will have the same size (in pixels) as the texture. You seem to be scaling that up by a *factor* of `CELL_SIZE`.

Comment: I am trying to scale the image (which is originally, I think, is 512 * 512 pixels), to 20 * 20. (CELL_SIZE is 20)

Comment: Oh I see. I misunderstood the functionality of setScale. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `setScale` sets the factor for scaling, not the actual dimensions.

For example, for an image with original dimensions of `512 * 512`, `setScale(20, 20)` will turn it to `(512 * 20) * (512 * 20)`